# Identify the rolled file name after programatic rollover of the file using logback

Tags: logback, rollover

I am using RollingFileAppender to rollover a file programatically.
However I would like to know the name of the file after what it is rolled to. 
Currently there is no way to know that.

Any idea how can I know that?

Answer (score 0):

I looked into the logback code but didn't find any custom hooks that we could add to get the file name. How about watching the file system using [Java 7 File Watching API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html)? Since you know the file path and the pattern you could easily determine the newly created file. Does that help?